# Скомпилировать декомпилированный файл отдельно

Tags: java, компиляция, декомпиляция

Помогите, пожалуйста, как мне декомпилировать отдельный зависимый от некоторых файлов класс. Чтобы изменить его и обратно без ошибок скомпилировать

Answer (score 0):

Есть прямо онлайн-декомпилятор: http://www.javadecompilers.com/